# Trying to keep the function going till a valid number is entered

Tags: c++, while-loop, factorial

I'm trying to make a program to calculate the factorial of the number given. But if the user enters a number which is less or equal to 0, I want the program to want it till he enter a number which is more than 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void facto(int a){
    int faktoriyel = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        faktoriyel *=i;
}
    cout << "The result:" << faktoriyel << endl;
}
int main(){
    int a;
    cout<<"Please enter a valid number:"; cin >> a;
    if(a<=0){
        cout<<"You entered an invalid number. Please try again.";
}
    while(a<=0);
    facto(a);
    return 0;

}
```

When I enter an invalid number, the program asks me to try again but i can't input any numbers. So my questions are:

a)How can I do it?

b)Is there anything unclear in my code?

c)What if I wanted the program to give me the results of the numbers I've entered, until I pressed enter button? How can I do it? (Like, I want it to give me the result of 3 4 and 5 in the order of 6 24 120 and then I press enter to end the program)

Comment: `while(a<=0);` is not how you write an actual `while` loop (this one is either endless or never executed)

Answer (score 2):

This here is not working:

```
while(a<=0);
```

The `;` is the function body of the `while` loop. On its own, it does nothing, and it doesn't affect the preceding `if` loop. So basically, the result is an infinite loop that does nothing forever if `a <= 0`. Instead, try this:

```
int a;
cout<<"Please enter a valid number:"; cin >> a;
while(a<=0){
    cout<<"You entered an invalid number. Please try again.";
    cin >> a;
}
```

Now those two statements are in the body of the `while` and it should work as expected.

About c), that requires some tinkering because per default `cin` doesn't stop reading just because you hit enter. You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
void facto(int a){
    int faktoriyel = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        faktoriyel *=i;
    }
    cout << "The result:" << faktoriyel << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter a valid number:" << endl;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(cin, line);
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    int a;
    while (1) {
        stream >> a;
        if (!stream) {
            break;
        }
        if (a <= 0) {
            cout << "You entered an invalid number. Please try again." << endl;
        }
        else facto(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: It works perfectly! But since i'm pretty new to C++ programming, I couldn't get how it works after "std:: string line;" How does getline and stringstream work? What is stream(line)? God, my question just brought more questions...

Comment: `std::getline(cin, line);` tells it to get just one line, because otherwise `cin` isn't going to stop just because you hit enter. So now `line` is an `std::string` holding the numbers entered. We want it to behave like `cin` (which is an `std::istream`), so we use `stream(line)` to make an `std::stringstream` with the content of the line. Now it can be used in the `while` loop to stream numbers into `a`, just like how we used `cin` for that purpose before.

Comment: Thanks! I'll work on it a little more to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while to verify the validity of your number :

```
while (a<=0){
    cout<<"You entered an invalid number. Please try again.";
    cin >> a;
}
```